# How can I send data from the get_avatar() (Google Sign In) to my template?

Tags: django

I have integrated Google Sign In using social_django app although in order to get the profile photo / avatar of the user I have used get_avatar through django pipeline. Now the problem is that how can I send the url received in the get_avatar function to one of my templates?

I have tried using Render, HTTPResponse, HTTPResponseRedirect, JSONResponse but I'm not getting the desired results.

#### get_avatar():

```
def get_avatar(backend, strategy, details, response,
        user=None, *args, **kwargs):
    if backend.name == 'google-oauth2':
        try:
            url = response["picture"]
        except KeyError:
            url = response['image'].get('url')
```

The rendering of get_avatar function returns a empty dictionary to the template. Rather it should return the URL which we get from get_avatar function.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: That function doesn't return anything.

Comment: @DanielRoseman   So how can I get data from that function?

Comment: By returning something?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I tried returning but it just sending an empty dictionary.